# Is there a way to control my Nikon camera from laptop?

Tags: software

Is there a program that I can purchase so that I can use my laptop to view and control settings on my D3200 for shooting?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Looking for camera control software (for Nikon DSLR) to shoot time lapse](http://photo.stackexchange.com/questions/24209/looking-for-camera-control-software-for-nikon-dslr-to-shoot-time-lapse)

Comment: What you probably searching for is called tethered shooting. Try 'tethering D3200' on google. Gave the results I expected.

Comment: Many tethering applications that support other Nikon cameras do not support the D3xx0 models. This probably needs to be a separate question.

Answer (score 2):

I've used [digiCamControl](http://digicamcontrol.com/) a couple of times with my D7100 (although I haven't tried the newest versions). It's free and open source, and works quite well, except for a few quirks here and there.

Answer (score 0):

It depends on the camera. Look [here](https://www.phaseone.com/en/Products/Software/Capture-One-Pro/Supported-Cameras.aspx) to determine whether your camera is supported by Capture One and [here](https://helpx.adobe.com/lightroom/kb/tethered-camera-support.html) to determine if it is supported by Lightroom. There are also numerous other tools of questionable repute which you can find through Google.

Answer (score 0):

Nikon Camera Control Pro 2  is available in software stores, Amazon, B&H, etc.